# How to align images in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, images, alignment

I can't seem to be able to adequately align images in Word (tried 2007 and 2013).

I added the images and made all of them be arranged in Wrap Text as In Front of Text.

Selected all of them and tried aligning them to the middle, to the top.. aligning to page, aligning selected objects.. Nothing worked. I even tried setting it as Absolute Position but it still wouldn't work as expected. Here is a picture to better illustrate the scenario.

[image: Picture]

Can someone help me in this?

Comment: What do you want to align them with? You can set the Wrapping style as "In line with text" and they will stay all together and you can fix their position with your keyboard, spaces, tabs, etc.

Comment: I wanted them to align with each other.. It seems that In Line with Text might work, but then I will be able to arrange them horizontally (with spaces and tabs as you've mentioned) but not vertically.

Comment: Making the images float and align them gives unexpected results, and i've never found a reliable way to make it work. Taking a lesson from old Web Design practices, you can use tables to make In Line with Text images behave as expected, aligning them into table cells

Comment: That was a great workaround. I put a 3 column table inside each table cell and it worked very well. Although there *seems* to be no way of making them behave well out of the box (sometimes nudging the image with the arrow keys makes it go haywire, you'll press → and it'll go diagonally up!?!), putting them inside table cells was by far the best method in achieving uniformity. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable Object Snapping

1. Go to the `Layout` tab and the `Arrange` group
2. Click `Align` then `Grid Settings`

[image]

From there, it should have an checkbox for an option that says *"Snap Objects to other objects"*

[image]

Check that box and see if that helps!

Comment: My box was already checked to _Snap objects to other objects_ .. Strangely it did partially work, but always giving me different results. For instance, having them all selected and asking to Align to Top sometimes they would align accordingly (although not aligning to any standard line, not to the first object selected neither to the last), but if I put Align to Top again, all of the objects would go down a little, and repeatedly so how many times I asked it to align again. Very strange behavior that they should look into.

Comment: @Bear Hmm.  I do not really have another solution off the top of my head, although if I find anything I will be sure to share.  Feel free to do the same if you come across it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, and I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I was able to resize and realign images freely and manually in Word using the following options:

- Right click image
- Select Size and Position
- Select Text wrapping tab
- Choose "Square"
- Go to Position tab
- For vertical or horizontal, select "relative position" and change the drop box to "page"

Granted I don't know if these options will differ for your version of Word or your OS. Hope this is helpful, but if not, I wish you luck.

Comment: When you say “realign images freely and manually”, do you mean that you positioned them with your mouse (or other pointing device)?  If so, I believe that that’s not what the question is asking for; the OP wants to align the images *exactly;* it’s very hard to do that manually.  If you have a procedure for aligning images exactly, please describe it in a little more detail. … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to align  photos just do by the instructions as follows :
First select the photo you wanted, right click on it
Next click on text wrapping and select either square or tight
At last you can arrange how ever you want and also you want to repeat the process for number of photos.